# updateOrCreate no actualiza, solo crea (Laravel 5.8)

Tags: laravel, json, eloquent, controller

he intentado actualizar mis datos de mi datatable, estoy utilizando el metodo updateOrCreate, pero el problema es que al editar mi dato, este me crea uno nuevo con otra id.

Esta es mi función en el controller

```
public function storeClase(Request $request){ // CREAR O EDITAR CLASE

  $data = json_decode($request->getContent());

  $data_clase = $data->clase;

  horarioModel::updateOrCreate(
    [
        'id_horario' => $request->id_horario_clase?: NULL
    ],
    [
        'clase'          => $data_clase->numero_clase,
        'fecha'          => $data_clase->fecha_clase_dt,
        'hora'           => $data_clase->hora_clase_dt,
        'id_curso'       => $data_clase->id_curso_clase,
        'id_alumno'      => $data_clase->id_alumno_clase,
        'minutos_bloque' => $data_clase->bloque_dt,
        'id_profesor'    => $data_clase->profesor_dt,
        'id_vehiculo'    => $data_clase->vehiculo_dt,
        'tipo'           => 'practica'
    ]
  );

  return response()->json();
}
```

esto es lo que recibe el json (decodificado)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿está funcionando correctamente (según lo que intentas hacer) el operador ternario?

Comment: si quiero crear funciona bien, pero cuando quiero actualizar algun dato, en vez de reemplazar ese dato en mi columna de la db, me crea un nuevo elemento con los datos que obtiene del json, pero con otra id, como dice el titulo, solo crea, no actualiza

Comment: Creo que no entendiste mi pregunta... estoy hablando del operador ternario.

Comment: Ah, perdón, soy nuevo en el tema de programación, desconozco ese termino, a que te refieres con ello?

Comment: Por qué a ese lo tomas del request? `'id_horario' => $request->id_horario_clase` seguramente te está dando null. Tómalo del json decodificado como a los demás `'id_horario' => $data_clase->id_horario_clase`

Comment: justamente era eso, por mas que mirara no lo habia visto u.u, gracias otra vez @porloscerrosΨ